# How to add a event listener in prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

The browsers thorw an error(Uncaught TypeError: this.showCheckedNums is not a function) When I click a checkbox.

**HTML Souce Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dth XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/Dth/xhtml1-transitional.dth">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check0" name="ck" />num1
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="check1" name="ck"/>num2
 <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="check2" name="ck"/>num3
 <input type="checkbox" value="8" id="check3" name="ck"/>num4
 <hr />
 result：<label id="ckRes">0</label>
 <hr /> 
</body>
</html>
<script>
 function ckCheck (mask,name) {
  this.mask = mask;//mask code
  this.name = name;//css selector
  this.temp = mask;//cache
  this.nodes = [];
 }
 ckCheck.prototype={
  start:function () {
   this.nodes = document.getElementsByName(this.name);
   this.default();
   this.addEvtLisener();
  },
  showCheckedNums:function(argument){
   document.getElementById("ckRes").innerHTML= this.temp;
  },
  default:function (argument) {
            //back to initial value
   for(var j = 0;j<this.nodes.length ;j++){
    //init checkbox
    this.nodes[j].checked = this.nodes[j].value & this.mask ;//1
   };
   this.showCheckedNums();
  },
  addEvtLisener:function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++){
    this.nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     
     e.target.checked ? this.temp|=e.target.value:this.temp^=e.target.value;
     //this.temp can be accessed correctly.
     this.showCheckedNums();
    })
   }
  },
 }
 var obj = new ckCheck(7,"ck")
 obj.start();
</script>
```

I am a beginner ，I don't konw why the error happened.I hope someone can help me to explain the error,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code without the error.

I suggest you read up on the `this` keyword, because it is very confusing when you're a JS beginner. Here is one explanation: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dth XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/Dth/xhtml1-transitional.dth">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check0" name="ck" />num1
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="check1" name="ck"/>num2
 <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="check2" name="ck"/>num3
 <input type="checkbox" value="8" id="check3" name="ck"/>num4
 <hr />
 result：<label id="ckRes">0</label>
 <hr /> 
</body>
</html>
<script>
 function ckCheck (mask,name) {
  this.mask = mask;//mask code
  this.name = name;//css selector
  this.temp = mask;//cache
  this.nodes = [];
 }
 ckCheck.prototype={
  start:function () {
   this.nodes = document.getElementsByName(this.name);
   this.default();
   this.addEvtLisener();
  },
  showCheckedNums:function(argument){
   document.getElementById("ckRes").innerHTML= this.temp;
  },
  default:function (argument) {
            //back to initial value
   for(var j = 0;j<this.nodes.length ;j++){
    //init checkbox
    this.nodes[j].checked = this.nodes[j].value & this.mask ;//1
   };
   this.showCheckedNums();
  },
  addEvtLisener:function(){
            var self = this;
   for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++){
    self.nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     
     e.target.checked ? self.temp|=e.target.value:self.temp^=e.target.value;
     //this.temp can be accessed correctly.
     self.showCheckedNums();
    })
   }
  },
 }
 var obj = new ckCheck(7,"ck")
 obj.start();
</script>
```

Comment: In this raw :`e.target.checked ? this.temp|=e.target.value:this.temp^=e.target.value;`,if the  this  keyword is not object of ckCheck,why this.temp can get   correct value?It's  confused for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look to hard at your code, I only fixed the error message. `this.temp` will be `undefined`. I updated the code to use `self`.

Comment: Thank you so much,but `this.temp` is not `undefined` ,instead,It have a value.I also think `this.temp` will be `undefined`.So, I think there is some other details,but I don't konw.

Comment: I see, `this.temp` is `undefined` .when `undefined` | `e.target.value`,the result must be `e.target.value`,In a word,this is a problem of scope,thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

The function where you add `.addEventListener`, you need to bind that function to your `this` object, like this:

```
this.nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.checked ? this.temp|=e.target.value:this.temp^=e.target.value;
                //this.temp can be accessed correctly.
    this.showCheckedNums();
}.bind(this));
```

Notice the `.bind(this)` I added. There are four ways how `this` is determined in JavaScript functions. See this [lecture](https://youtu.be/ya4UHuXNygM?t=15m27s).

A better way to do what you are trying to do would be like this:

```
function onClick(e) {
    e.target.checked ? this.temp|=e.target.value:this.temp^=e.target.value;
    this.showCheckedNums();
};
var onClickBound = onClick.bind(this);
this.nodes[i].addEventListener('click', onClickBound);
```

Comment: Thank you so much,Let me learned a new method to bind `this`.I had solved this confusion about scope with your help.